# Get javascript variable on the server side in Vaadin 8

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I have some client side javascript code which is used for some user interaction. This javascript code stores a result in a variable. Is it possible to get this variable with server side code? Unfortunately the `callFunction` method of `AbstractJavaScriptComponent` does not have a return value.

Please note that I don't want to call do a server rpc from the client side.

Comment: Of course this is not possible, unless you send the data to the server first.

Comment: @CBroe why would you downvote the question. Have you even noticed that this javascript question is related to Vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the documentation of Vaadin, what you ask for is not possible. See the docs:

- [Integrate Client and Server-Side with a connector](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-connector.html)
- [RPC Calls](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-rpc.html)

It's also not possible if you think about the technical specs. What you want is in fact the server requesting the client to return something - which is not possible by design. You will have to issue some kind of request from the client to the server to provide your variable data - there is simply no other way.

With vaadin, the simplest way to do so is using the RPC-interfaces the framework provides. You can of course write your own xml-request, but why would you want to do so? The simplest way to send data from client to server when using vaadin is by using the RPC calls.